# Microsoft Virtual Wi-Fi Hosted Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet

I have a computed connected to the internet via a wired connection, and it has a Wi-Fi adapter. I want to turn that into a hotspot so I can connect my cellphone / netbook to the internet through it.

I've followed various guides in how to set the hosted network, doing the following:

1. netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myssid key=mypassword keyUsage=persistent
2. Going to Network Connections, **Properties** on my Wired Connection, selecting the newly created Virtual WiFi connection (named "Wireless Network Connection"), and clicking on *"Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection"*.
3. Clicking Setting and checking all boxes of services that I'm sharing.
4. netsh wlan start hostednetwork
5. **Status** of the Virtual WiFi and checking the IPv4 Connectivity: Internet
6. Had to change the IPv4 settings of it to use the following address: 192.168.137.1, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
7. Opening my Android phone, enabling WiFi, connecting to the new wireless connection and... success!
8. Testing by browsing any site... failed.

I've disabled the Windows Firewall and even the Router's, but nothing changed. Tried restarting the Virtual WiFi multiple times, still nothing changed.
I'm successfully connecting to the WiFi, using *"netsh wlan show hostednetwork"* I can see my Android device connected, but it just doesn't have internet access.

What could be the issue?

Comment: From my experience it's not easy to route internet through a computer to a wireless adapter for broadcast. What's happening for you at the moment is the wireless adapter is letting your android to connect to the wireless network, but it isnt taking your computer's internet and feeding it through. I'm not entirely sure this is possible in the first place, for that matter... I'd consult the product's vendor.

Answer (score 0):

> Going to Network Connections, Properties on my Wired Connection,
>   selecting the newly created Virtual WiFi connection (named "Wireless
>   Network Connection"), and clicking on "Allow other network users to
>   connect through this computer's Internet connection".

Your virtual WiFi connection will most probably be named "Wireless Network Connection 2". Select it from the dropdown box